# How can I draw a rectangle around an object from background subtraction

Tags: c#

How can I draw a rectangle around an object from background subtraction by C#, I searched too much but I can't find the answer for me.
Hope somebody help.

[image]

The rectangle is around people.

Comment: `From background substraction` ?? U mean u want to remove the backgorund/make the background transparent?

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? 
__Always__ TAG your question correctly!

Comment: By getting software that does this for you. Or you could study image processing/feature extraction/pattern recognition/neuronal networks/etc.. Choose whatever is the easier and more comfortable approach for you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are talking (taking into consideration the images provided) is pedestrian detection. This is a [well known problem on Computer Vision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pedestrian_detection)

If you want to accomplished this task I would recommend you use [OpenCV](https://opencv.org/) a widely used library on Computer Vision, although it is originally developed on Phyton and C/C++ there is a [wrapper for c#](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Main_Page)

Here there is an example (code included) about how to achieve the pedestrian detection on CSharp

[pedestrian detection on CSharp](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Pedestrian_Detection_in_CSharp)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I'm using Windows Form C#, I want to draw a rectangle around object (not only people) car, animal, etc, .. from background subtract

Sorry for my bad English